# How to hide boot messages (silent boot) in debian jessie (raspberry pi)?

Tags: debian, boot, systemd, raspberry-pi

I'm working with raspberry pi. Previously (debian wheezy), I used the following codes to hide boot messages and have a silent boot, until a code (playing `omxplayer` on loop) would run from `/etc/rc.local`. So I was able to successfully hide the boot messages.

***/boot/cmdline.txt :***

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty2 kgdboc=ttyAMA0,115200 elevator=deadline root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 rootwait logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 loglevel=2 quiet
```

***/etc/init.d/rc.local :***

```
...
...
chvt 2 && clear && setterm -foreground black && clear
```

Unfortunately, after upgrading to Jessie, this method does not work fully. Most of the boot messages are hidden, but a few lines at the end of the boot are visible (before the code starts to run from `/etc/rc.local`). The following logs are visible on boot:

```
[    3.492591] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_drivestrengthinit: No SDIO Drive strength init done for chip 43430 rev 1 pmurev 24
[    4.496428] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
[    5.506547] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_htclk: HT Avail timeout (1000000): clkctl 0x50
```

Also, the following log is visible on reboot or shutdown:

```
[ 87.728033] watchdog watchdog0: watchdog did not stop!
```

***So, how can I hide the boot messages and logs COMPLETELY in Jessie?***

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this into cmdline

```
quiet splash loglevel=0 rd.systemd.show_status=quiet rd.udev.log-priority=3
```