# How to change the color of boot logs in Debian?

Tags: debian, boot, logs, colors

OS: Debian Jessie (8)

How can I change the color of all the logs and text during the initial boot (and also the final shutdown) to black?
(including the login user/password prompt) !?

My goal is to have a completely silent boot, where no text is shown.

Comment: Are you aware that hiding boot-time messages makes debugging boot crashes extremely difficult?  if this is for you, you'll end up kicking yourself one day.  If this is for your users, they'll hate you.

Comment: You turn off your system? Weird!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/286840/ is a much better question.

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequences used by systemd are ***hardcoded*** in the program, like this:

```
#define WHITE_ON_BLACK "\033[40;37;1m"
#define NORMAL "\033[0m"

static void print_border(FILE *output, unsigned width) {
        unsigned x, y;

        /* Four rows of border */
        for (y = 0; y < 4; y += 2) {
                fputs(WHITE_ON_BLACK, output);
```

and making it configurable has not been a priority.  What you want would require that, e.g., by providing a way to change the colors used (black-on-black is a special case that wouldn't be invisible for all terminals anyway).

Color configuration has been suggested as an enhancement, but the developers are unresponsive, providing an *environment variable* but no global *configuration setting* (which would affect boot-time).  And even that doesn't appear in jessie:

```
$ dpkg -l systemd
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  systemd        215-17+deb8u amd64        system and service manager
```

The available patch-level is **`215-17`**, while the environment variable appears in **`219`**.

Reading the [manual page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html), it appears that to do what you want, you'd (somehow) "upgrade" to patch 219 and modify all of the systemd configurations to take advantage of this feature.

Further reading:

- [Bug #90464 - RFE: systemd optionally turn off colors](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=90464)
- [Debian Bug report logs - #785350
  systemd - systemctl(1) please add option / make nocolor the deafult output](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=785350)
- [What Is 508 Compliance?](http://www.508checker.com/what-is-508-compliance)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasDickey for your answer. Is there an easier solution to have a silent boot with all the messages hidden !?